# Extracting max value in GridView column in a Web Performance Test

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, performance-testing

This pertains to .NET Web Performance Tests.

If I have an ASP.NET page with a GridView that has a column of `int`s, how do I write an extraction rule to get the largest `int` in the column?

I tried creating a custom extraction rule by inheriting from `ExtractionRule` and in the `Extract` method using `e.Response.HtmlDocument.GetFilteredHtmlTags` however, the `HtmlTag`s returned don't seem to expose their `innerHtml` contents.

Comment: Where does your GridView get its data from? Wouldn't it be more appropriate the query the data source instead of the element that displays it?

Comment: That's a great point, @Serv. How would I get the max of a column from the datasource?

Comment: What is your datasource? Is it a database? datatable? How did you bind the data to your gridview? Just give us some more information to play around with. Best solution would include some sample data so we can rebuild your problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can write an extraction rule that gets the whole column, then process the numbers to get their maximum value. Alternatively, use a built-in extraction rule to get the whole column, then write a plugin to get the maximum value. In either case your code should expect a mixture of numbers and other text.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Day has a great blog post containing two types that express similar concerns. TableColumnValueValidator and ExtractRandomValueFromTable.

http://www.benday.com/2013/08/19/validation-extraction-rules-for-visual-studio-2012-web-performance-tests/

In the Extract(object, ExtractionEventArgs), you need to parse the ExtractionEventArgs.Response.BodyString. Ben uses the HtmlAgilityPack library for this. http://www.nuget.org/packages/htmlagilitypack

Something like this is roughly the code you'd need. This is simliar logic to ExtractRandomValueFromTable.

This does not account for thead/tbody or cells that span multiple columns/rows.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(e.Response.BodyString);
HtmlNode table = doc.GetElementbyId(TableId); // TableId is a test property
HtmlNodeCollection columns = table.SelectNodes("//th");
int columnIndex = FindColumnIndexByName(columns, ColumnName); // ColumnName is a test property
HtmlNodeCollection rows = table.SelectNodes("//tr")
int maxValue = Int32.MinValue;
foreach(HtmlNode row in rows)
{
   HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("./td");
   // Todo check for bounds of cells here
   HtmlNode cell = cells[columnIndex];
   int value = Int32.MinValue;
   Int32.TryParse(cell.InnerText.Trim(), out value);
   maxValue = Math.Max(value, maxValue);
}
e.WebTest.Context.Add(ContextParameterName, maxValue);

int FindColumnIndexByName(HtmlNodeCollection columns, string columnName)
{
   for(int i=0; i<columns.Count; i++)
   if (String.Equals(columns[i].InnerText, columnName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
     return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
```